# Rotated ViewPager is hard to swipe

Tags: java, android

So I have a layout that contains 2 ViewPager which take up the entire screen. The first ViewPager takes up the top half on the screen and has a rotation of 180 and the other takes up the bottom and has no rotation. When the application is running, the rotated ViewPager is hard to swipe and I can't figure out why. In order to swipe it, I have to move my finger the full horizontal distance of the screen. Does anyone know why this might be behaving this way?

Comment: @MikeM. I will look into ViewPager2. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, hang on a second. I misread your question, thinking you meant a 90° rotation. Sorry about that. You meant that the rotated `ViewPager` is upside-down, basically, right? If that's the case, you can probably just stick with the regular `ViewPager`, with no rotation, and start it from the last page. You would instead rotate the pages, rather than the whole `ViewPager`.

Comment: Please attach an image what you want